# Enum not returning from webapi call

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, enums

I have a seperate Enum class like this:

```cs
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public enum AStatus
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "Unverified")]
    Unverified = 0,

    [EnumMember(Value = "Verified")]
    Verified = 1,

    [EnumMember(Value = "Error")]
    Error = 2,

    [EnumMember(Value = "ServiceDown")]
    ServiceDown = 3,
}
```

And I am using it like this:

```cs
[DataContract]
public partial class ResultDto
{
    [DataMember(Name="status", EmitDefaultValue=false)]
    public AStatus Status { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "someOtherObjectList ", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public List<SomeOtherObject> SomeOtherObjectList { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "messages", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Messages { get; set; }

    public string ToJson()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, Formatting.Indented);
    }
}
```

If I attach to the call, until ok(res), I have all properties but when I look at browser's network respose, Enum property is missing, I mean it's not in resultDto at all.

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("/someoperation")]
[ValidateModelState]
[SwaggerOperation("Check")]
[SwaggerResponse(200, typeof(List<ResultDto>), "successful operation")]
[SwaggerResponse(400, typeof(List<ResultDto>), "Invalid")]
public virtual IActionResult Check([FromBody] RequestDto requestDto)
{
    var res = _aService.Check(requestDto);
    return Ok(res); // until here response object has enum and it's value
}
```

Comment: Is this correct?: `[SwaggerResponse(200, typeof(List<RequestDto>), "successful operation")]
[SwaggerResponse(400, typeof(List<RequestDto>), "Invalid")]`

Comment: @DKDhilip I changed Request to ResponseDto but still no fix

Answer (score 0):

Remove EmitDefaultValue=false if you want to use the default value of the Enum, if not so you have to set the value of the Status

```
[DataMember(Name="status")]
public AStatus Status { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

enable Null Value Handling

```
 services.AddMvc(options =>
        {...}).AddJsonOptions(jsonOptions =>
        {
            jsonOptions.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
            jsonOptions.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            jsonOptions.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include;
        })
```